# I am getting error with my longtable when I use footnotes

Tags: footnotes, longtable

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}        
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}



\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{longtable}[c]{cllllll}
    \caption{Table caption} \label{tablelabel} \\
    \toprule
       some toprule \\
    \midrule
    \endhead

    longtable

    \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
 \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
    Footnote tex
 \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}
 \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

and the error that I get:

```
[58])
Runaway argument?
{\begin {threeparttable} \begin {longtable}[c]{cllllll} \caption {Ads\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \Gscale@box@dd.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.169 \input ch2

?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is from `\resizebox` not having a closing brace.  However, you can't use `\resizebox` on something that spreads over more than one page.  Furthermore, `threeparttable` does not work with `longtable`, you need to use the package [`threeparttablex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttablex) instead.  Here is an example based on the essentials of your code:

[image: Sample top][image: Sample bottom]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,fixltx2e}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{TableNotes}
  \item[a] Footnote tex
  \end{TableNotes}
  \begin{longtable}[c]{cl}
    \caption{Table caption} \label{tablelabel} \\
    \toprule
    some &headings\tnote{a} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \insertTableNotes
    \endlastfoot
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    longtable &material\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this is giving the same error, I cannot add footnote under my table. By the way the table uses landscape environment and takes two pages.

Comment: Sorry my `\endlastfoot` was incorrectly placed.  Now corrected, and example extended to spread over more than one page.  The landscape mode is not part of the problem.